# How should look link the json response so that ActiveResource may generate a DateTime object from a date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, activeresource

I have a question object with a created_at attribute in it. When I will find a question i get back the created_at from the REST service, but Activeresource do not convert the date string to DateTime.

```
Question.find(1)
/questions/1.json

Question.find(1).created_at.class
=> String
```

In which format should be the Json response, so that ActiveResource will convert it to a DateTime?

If it is not possible, what should i do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to slide #14 in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/wolframarnold/consuming-rest-services-with-activeresource), you can do this in `config/initializers/active_resource.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.use_standard_json_time_format = true
ActiveSupport.parse_json_times = true
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON will always be a string as this is how it passes data as stringyfied objects.  If you want to convert it to a date/time object you will need to parse it at the server side.

`Time.parse` should do the trick

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse

Comment: But i need the json structure, because my rest service is in perl not in Rails.